# NodeJs kubernetes request and limits best practices

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We are operating multiple nodejs applications in an EKS cluster. Occasionally we have peaks in request numbers which are causing performance problems even so we set resource requests/limits and use HPAs to scale the applications. At the moment we are using the following requests/limits:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 1400m
    memory: 800Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 2000m
    memory: 800Mi
```

It seems to be a combination of problems based on very strict liveness probe settings and cpu throttling caused by settings the limits. I try to find a good best practice specifically for nodejs applications on how to set the requests/limits. Of course, removing the limits will help with the problem.

Does anyone here have a recommendation or experience to share?

Thanks for your help in advance!

PS: I read the following blogs posts

- https://medium.com/pipedrive-engineering/how-we-choked-our-kubernetes-nodejs-services-932acc8cc2be
- https://medium.com/blablacar/operating-node-js-in-kubernetes-at-scale-at-blablacar-3afb6d5d4299

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anybody looking for answers:

1. Remove the CPU limits - the kernel scheduler will take care of limiting the CPU if the node is starving. And configure cluster auto-scaling for the case where you need more CPU.
2. Regarding memory requests and limits and cpu requests - no rule of thumb will help here - each app resource consumption is different - dependent on the  quality of code, tasks performed and current load. Тhe best way is to run the application for a while (with real or mocked production traffic), measuring it's actual consumption, observing if any OOM or CPU throttling occurs. And then setting the requests/limits according to the actual needs.